# Trouble understanding the runtime complexitiy of a function

Tags: python, runtime, time-complexity

I'm currently studying for an exam and the question is as follows; Given function:

```
def foo(lst):
   count = 0
   while len(lst)>1:
       mid = len(lst)//2
       lst = lst[:mid]
       count += lst[-1]
   return count
```

What is its runtime complexitiy?

To my understanding, the outer while loop will run `logn` times due to the list being cut in half each time. Slicing is an O(n) activity, hence, the runtime would be `nlogn`. Unfortunately, the answers claim the runtime is O(n). Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Slicing is indeed *O(n)*, but the second time, since the list is already cut in half, it will take *n/2*, then *n/4*, etc.

Comment: Ahh, that's tricky. They have told us n/2 + n/4.... is O(n). Thank you, if you post as an answer I shall accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: Slicing a list runs in *O(n)*, but since the list is each time cut in half, that means that the *n* in the second iteration is half of the previous one.

If slicing to *k* takes exactly *k* "instructions", then this means that the algorithm comes down to the sum of *n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... + 1*, or more formal:

```
log n
---     n
\      ---
/        i
---     2
i=1
```

The above is a [*geometric serie* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) is equal to:

```
  n/2         n/2
------- - 1 = --- - 1 = n - 1
1 - 1/2       1/2
```

So the total number of instructions is *O(n)*.